# How to login windows application using c# just like sessions in asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, windows

I am developing an web application, so now i have a requirement to develop a 
  login page so in my app nearly 20 forms and 1 master page.

So i designed 1 login form i stored the details in sql db and i checked all
  the credentials everything is working.

But when the user login from login page i showed the master form in that 
  nearly 20 forms are there with linklabel. So when the master page is opened
  i showed his name on top of the master page. It is fine. I showed this name

Login form:

```
  master MasterObj = new master();

  MasterObj.values = this;

  MasterObj.Show();
```

In master form:

```
  string login values;

   label1.text=values.txtusername.text;
```

So i successfully dispalyed message on this master form.

So the subforms also there is linklabel to redirect master form, then there
   is a problem to dispaly name "object reference cannot instance of an object".
   i know why this error came? beacause i am not intialize the name value from
   the subform.

Which is the best way to get then name of the user to all the win forms 
   in my application thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Loginclass  that handles the Login User ID ,  and once logged you can set the value

```
 public static LoggedUser{
    public Static string userid;
    }
```

in each form on load you can check the userid if not empty .

or you can get benefit from the settings property

```
    Settings.Default.UserID = UserID.Text;
        Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Is LoggedUser is static class or not?

Comment: yes ? any problem with that ? or as I mentioned you can save your values in the settings property

Comment: Yes i want to change my all business logic if the class is static

Comment: how can i assign username value in this loggeduser class? show me?

Comment: i assigned like this in my login.cs page:  LoggedUser.userid = txtname.Text;

Comment: yes that is correct way , but I am saying again for more easy practice just use  Settings.Default.UserID = UserID.Text;
        Settings.Default.Save();

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static variable in Program.cs file and then you can access it from through out the application like

declare the variable in program .cs file as

public static string LoggedUser="";

assign the username to it like

Program.LoggedUser=txtUserName.Text;

And Accessing it through out the application is like

string UserName=Program.LoggedUser.ToString();